# Waitlisted - Got Paper Accepted - Email Committee?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions

I have been waitlisted to a top program in CS. During the time I applied to the program and now, I received the rebuttal results of a paper I had submitted and worked on over the last year. I got two strong accepts, and 1 weak accept, as first author at a top conference. There is potential for this paper to be an Oral paper as well.

Should I email the committee requesting to update my resume? Although having  strong accepts is usually a guarantee for admission, it is still not official until mid March, but it may be too late by then. Also, are the waitlist positions already set in stone, or can this update of my resume move me up on the waitlist. Is this even worth it to do?

Please give me your advice.

Comment: If the paper is still under review, it has not been accepted. Emailing the committee will just make you seem utterly naive.

Comment: That was my feeling as well..hmm. I have never seen anyone put "Strong accept in Rebuttal" in their resume, so I assume this holds true as well